# Show component on button click from one component in angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I have one "+" button in navbar which is inside

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

when i click on that i want to show component

```
<app-stepper></app-stepper>
```

This is my main parent app.component.html

```
  <app-navbar></app-navbar>
  <app-stepper></app-stepper>
  <app-test></app-test>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup an [event emitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) in the `app-navbar` that emits when the `+` button is clicked. Then bind this event to an `app-stepper` show/hide toggler.

navbar.component.ts

```js
export class NavbarComponent {
  @Output() onPlusClick = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  plusClick() {
    ...
    this.onPlusClick.emit(true);
  }
}
```

navbar.component.html

```
<button (mouseup)="plusClick()">+</button>
...
```

app.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent {
  toggleStepper = false;
  ...
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<app-navbar (onPlusClick)="toggleStepper = !toggleStepper"></app-navbar>
<app-stepper *ngIf="toggleStepper"></app-stepper>
```

Here I toggle the `app-stepper` everytime the `+` is clicked regardless of the event emitted by the `onPlusClicked` emitter. If you wish to bind the `toggleStepper` directly to the event emitted, you could do so by emitting the correct boolean in the `navbar` component and assigning it directly to the `toggleStepper` variable.

navbar.component.ts

```js
plusClicked() {
  this.onPlusClicked.emit(true);
  // or `this.onPlusClicked.emit(false)` based on some condition 
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<!-- here the `event$` is either `true` or `false` -->
<app-navbar (onPlusClick)="toggleStepper = $event"></app-navbar>
<app-stepper *ngIf="toggleStepper"></app-stepper>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shared service that is injected both into `<app>` and `<app-navbar>`

The Service would look somewhat like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SharedService{

  public showStepper: boolean = false;
}
```

It holds a boolean that says if the stepper should be shown or not.

Inside of `<app-navbar>`, when the user clicks the '+', set `showStepper` to `true`.

Next, inside of `<app>`, make a public property that returns the value of `showStepper` inside of the service like this:

```
public get showStepper(): boolean {
    return this._sharedService.showStepper;
    // _sharedService is the injected Service
}
```

And now inside of `<app.component.html>`, use the `*ngIf directive` to conditionally show your stepper component:

`<app-stepper *ngIf="showStepper"></app-stepper>`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it as shown in [this stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-show-comp-on-btn-click).

You need to use an Output variable in the navbar component and emit a value on the `+` button click.
In the `app component`, you need to watch for the event emitted by the navbar component and use that event value to show or hide the `stepper component`.